# Row size of igxGrid and line break of igxDialog

Tags: infragistics, ignite-ui-angular, igx-grid

I have two questions about igxGrid and igxDialog.

1. How can I set the height of the rows in a igxGrid?
2. I have a confirmation dialog with a message with 3 sentences. How can I include a new line after each sentence? The `'\n'` and `<br>` do not work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

1. To set grid rows height you should set [rowHeight](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/docs/typescript/latest/classes/IgxGridComponent.html#rowHeight) of the grid like this:

```html
<igx-grid [rowHeight]="100">
...
</igx-grid>
```

2. Message is used to show simple message in the dialog. It is put in a span and there is no way to make it multiline. If you need to show multiline text in the dialog body you can add it as a content in the dialog like this:

```html
<igx-dialog>
    Some multilne
    <br />
    messge here!
</igx-dialog>
```

Note you can put whatever you want as a dialog content. Keep in mind if you set `message` input it will override the content.